# How to propertly permanently rename network interface in LXLE?

Tags: ubuntu, network-interface, rename, lxde, wlan

I have a `LXLE 18.04 LTS` and wlan adapter with name `wlp7s0b1`, which I'm not comfortable with.

Recommended by all `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` is not present in my installation, although `udev` is.
`/lib/udev/rules.d/75-persistent-net-generator.rules` is successfully missing from my distribution and `udevadm trigger --action=add` doesn't change anything.

I successfully created a link: `ln -s /lib/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules`, but there was no list devices therefore did not help.

`/etc/network/interfaces` in my installation does not contain anything useful, as a `netplan`.

During my attempts to find at least something, I came across the output of the `sudo udevadm info /sys/class/net/wlp7s0b1` command:

```
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.3/0000:07:00.0/bcma0:1/net/wlp7s0b1
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.3/0000:07:00.0/bcma0:1/net/wlp7s0b1
E: DEVTYPE=wlan
E: ID_BUS=pci
E: ID_MM_CANDIDATE=1
E: ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE=BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
E: ID_MODEL_ID=0x4727
E: ID_NET_NAME_MAC=wlx60d8190f1e84
E: ID_NET_NAME_PATH=wlp7s0b1
E: ID_OUI_FROM_DATABASE=Hon Hai Precision Ind. Co.,Ltd.
E: ID_PATH=pci-0000:07:00.0-bcma-1
E: ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_07_00_0-bcma-1
E: ID_PCI_CLASS_FROM_DATABASE=Network controller
E: ID_PCI_SUBCLASS_FROM_DATABASE=Network controller
E: ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=Broadcom Limited
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=0x14e4
E: IFINDEX=3
E: INTERFACE=wlp7s0b1
E: SUBSYSTEM=net
E: SYSTEMD_ALIAS=/sys/subsystem/net/devices/wlp7s0b1
E: TAGS=:systemd:
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=37531623
```

In this output, I am very interested in `pci-0000:07:00.0-bcma-1`. I believe this can be used as a unique identifier instead of a MAC. I would not like to be tied to MAC, since it can be changed with utilities like `macchanger`, and then, probably, the old name can return. Or is there a binding to the permanent MAC embedded in the chip?

**How do I permanently change the name of an interface based on its ID_PATH using udev? Is this renaming method correct?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am very interested in pci-0000:07:00.0-bcma-1. I believe this can be used as a unique identifier instead of a MAC.

Right, the `ID_PATH` can be used to rename the interface name.

Create a `/etc/systemd/network/10-rename-wlp7s0b1.link` with the following content:

```
[Match]
Path=pci-0000:07:00.0-bcma-1

[Link]
Name=wlan0
```

Changes will be applied after reboot.

Comment: A couple years later but glad I found this, will be testing this over the next few days. I'm using multiple usb ethernet adapters on a PI and they were changing interfaces without carefully planned plugging and unplugging during boot. Hoping this will solve my woes.